# I can't get different convolution results when calling the function successively with different parameters

Tags: c++, opencv, convolution

I am writing the Gaussian convolution function using cv::cuda::Convolution and calling the function with different parameters to get different convolution results to use in other processing. But I got the same results for all of three times calling with the result of the first parameter.

Following is the gaussian function.

```
void Gauss_conv(const cv::cuda::GpuMat& src,
    cv::cuda::GpuMat& conv,
    int gauss_size,
    bool convert_to_8bit = true)
{
    cv::Mat gauss_kernel;
    cv::cuda::GpuMat gf_src, gf_gauss, gf_conv;
    std::vector <cv::cuda::GpuMat> gfv_src, gfv_gauss,  gfv_conv;

    src.convertTo(gf_src, CV_32FC3);

    //Split the source image on the GPU
    cv::cuda::split(gf_src, gfv_conv);
    cv::cuda::split(gf_src, gfv_src);

    //Prepare the input image for Gauss filtering
    cv::cuda::copyMakeBorder(gf_src, gf_gauss, 0.5 * gauss_size,
        0.5 * gauss_size, 0.5 * gauss_size, 0.5 * gauss_size,
        cv::BORDER_REPLICATE);
    cv::cuda::split(gf_gauss, gfv_gauss);

    //Create the Gauss kernel and upload it to the GPU
    cv::Ptr < cv::cuda::Convolution> c1 = cv::cuda::createConvolution();
    cv::mulTransposed(cv::getGaussianKernel(gauss_size, -1, CV_32FC1),
        gauss_kernel, false);
    gf_gauss.upload(gauss_kernel);

    //Apply Gaussian blur to all channels independently, also compute subtraction image
    for (int i = 0; i < src.channels(); i++)
    {
        c1->convolve(gfv_gauss[i], gf_gauss, gfv_conv[i], true);
    }

    cv::cuda::merge(gfv_conv, conv);

}

//in main function
    cv::Mat srcFloat;
    src.convertTo(srcFloat, CV_32FC3);

    cv::cuda::GpuMat gpu_src_uchar(src);
    cv::cuda::GpuMat gpu_src_float(srcFloat);
    cv::cuda::GpuMat conv1, conv2, conv3;

    Gauss_conv(gpu_src_uchar, conv1, 131, true); //131
    Gauss_conv(gpu_src_uchar, conv2, 531, true); //531
    Gauss_conv(gpu_src_uchar, conv3, 1631, true); //1631
```

I want to get three different convolution results in main function. But I got the same result (first convolution result) for all the convolution in the main function.

[This is the image I use for testing.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dAs5O.png)

Comment: I tested your code and got 3 *different* results. Attach an image you use as input please.

Comment: @Oliort I've added the image I use for testing.